# Overriding Build Settings using .xcconfig in XCode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, arm64

I am curious about the effectiveness of indicating build settings in a .xcconfig file. When my enterprise app is built using Jenkins, the Valid Architectures automatically includes arm64, even when I exclude arm64 in my settings locally. This is causing some build issues in XCode, and I need to ensure that arm64 continues to be excluded from my build settings.

**My question is:** Can I hardcode build settings in my .xcconfig file that will override any changes made to my local build settings when a build goes through?

**Another question:** How does XCode determine where to retrieve its build settings from during a build? E.g. If I have settings in my .xcconfig as well as in the app Build Settings, which will XCode draw the settings from and how is that decided?